# A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spread

I have this code in `Typescript`:

```js
const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);
```

```js
const newHistory = history.slice(0, currentStep + 1);
```

and when I want to set new State using spread operators like that:

```
setHistory(...newHistory);
```

I have errors:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

Can someone can help my, how I can properly types this?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41140074/6908282) is the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 43):

To put this simply:

Because you're using the spread operator directly, you're passing in multiple arguments to your `useState` function, but `useState` functions only accept a single argument. Instead, use the spread operator to create a single array, and pass that in.

```js
const newObject = [...newHistory];
setHistory(newObject);

// or, even simpler: 
setHistory([...newHistory]);

// NOT the below - this is passing in multiple arguments.
setHistory(...newHistory);
```

Comment: huh, why an object?

Comment: Oops - forgot the OP was dealing with an array rather than an object. (It works for objects, too.) Thanks, @Sulthan, good catch!

Answer (score 39):

In general, you can avoid such errors by using apply

```
setHistory(...newHistory); //drops error

setHistory.apply(null, newHistory) //works
```

but in your example there's a problem:
you init history with `[[null, null, null...]]`
then get it, slice to `[[null, null, ...], ...]`
and try to set it back as `setHistory([null, null], null)`.

it seems that you just need to use `setHistory(newHistory);`

Comment: What about calling `super()` in a class constructor? You can't use `apply` then

Comment: I have no idea :), I come to this question by searching error that occurred in ts project without react, and found a general answer. 
So may be you can provide simpler solution in react context, which is not provided by the author.

Comment: Recommending to avoid errors by using things that rely on `any` instead of actually addressing the root cause (which you did only in the second half of your answer) is not a good idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me perfectly!

```
setHistory(...(newHistory as []));
```

Comment: This indeed makes the Typescript error go away - but would be incorrect for this question which wants you to pass an array to `setHistory` not function parameters

Comment: this worked in my scenario! not the same as OP.  I had a class that was extending another class and had to pass the rest of the arguments from my constructor to it's super() method.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue as I'm new to React and Js, trying to spread an object, using `useState` to set the new value of the object using it's previous value.

```
const onChange = ({name, value}: OnChangeFormType) => {
  setForm(prev => {...prev, [name]: value});
};
```

However I didn't account for the fact that it's a function, and it should have been either wrapped in `()` or add a `return`. Personally I prefer just wrapping in `()` like below.

```
const onChange = ({name, value}: OnChangeFormType) => {
  setForm((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
};
```

or

```
const onChange = ({name, value}: OnChangeFormType) => {
  setForm(prev => { return {...prev, [name]: value}});
};
```

This was a head scratcher for me, until it clicked.

Answer (score 1):

When using `useState`, index `1` in the tuple returned is `setHistory`. That should only accept one argument (the new value). The example in the original post is spreading the history into potentially 8 arguments. It needs to be passed as an array which can be as simple as `setHistory(newHistory)`.

If the intention is to always modify the previous state, I would call `setHistory(previousHistory => previousHistory.slice(x, y))`.

Also! For Typescript, you need to declare a type for useState like this `useState<History[]>(Array(9).fill(null));` Without declaring a type, typescript is going to infer something that, in this case, may not be what you want.

Just note, you don't always need to declare a type for useState. Actually, I'd encourage using type inference whenever possible. If the initial value is null or undefined, you won't be able to use type inference in Typescript.

Answer (score -2):

It can be resolved by assign the value to variable.

```
const latestHistory = {...newHistory}

setHistory(latestHistory);
```