# Typescript - A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter

Tags: typescript, react-native, spread-syntax

I am having some problems with this error:

```
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
```

and my code looks like this:

```
  const [item, setItem] = useState<string>();
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);


  const handleAddItem = () => {
  console.log(item);
  setItems(...items, item);

}

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddItem()}>
      <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

I have searched the other questions posted about this topic but could not seem to fix it with any of those provided. Any ideas and inputs are appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768781/a-spread-argument-must-either-have-a-tuple-type-or-be-passed-to-a-rest-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the state which is an array; you were very close but you missed the brackets:

```
setItems([...items, item]);
```

Comment: I tried that too and this would give me this error `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Comment: You need to also pass a generic to useState: `useState<string[]>([]);`

Comment: Thanks! I tried declaring the array but couldn't figure it out, after that it still complained but I put exclamation marks "!" after the variables in setItems() `setItems([...items!, item!]);` and it all works great now. Thanks again!