# Typescript error using spread operator in function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use the spread operator in the `sendMessage` function for websockets. I get the error that the spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. `sendMessage` uses `...values` as a rest parameter. What am I missing?

My problem is that test could be of arbitrary length (but will always contain one element).

```
const sendMessage = (type: string, ...values: (string | number)[]) =>
  websocket.connected_socket.send(`${type}=${values.join("~")}`);

let test = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
sendMessage(...test) // error: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)
sendMessage(...["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]) // this is fine
```

EDIT: This works. I guess it had something to do with the parameters of the function

```
sendMessage(test[0], ...test.slice(1))
```

Comment: What's the signature of your `sendMessage` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768781/a-spread-argument-must-either-have-a-tuple-type-or-be-passed-to-a-rest-parameter)

Comment: test needs to be const instead of let.

Answer (score 2):

Try `as const`:

```
const test = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] as const
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to solve this. But let us see why the error arises.

[image]

The default type of `test` will be an `string[]`. The error mentions that spread argument can be a tuple, but here we have an array.
A [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) is just like an array but the length is fixed and also the type of element at each index is fixed.

```
const sendMessage= (type: string, ...values: (string | number)[]) => {

};
```

If we spread an empty array, we would get no elements. The function would not work as expected. Hence spearing an array type is something that should be disallowed, which is exactly what is happening.

To pass the correct arguments, it is better to be more restrictive. And tuple is the way to do it.

1. Define `test` like this:

```
const test : [string,string,string,string,string]= ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

2. As mentioned in another answer, use `const` [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). It will give the most exact type typescript can infer. Array literals become readonly tuples.

```
const test = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] as const;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=49&pln=3&pc=1#code/PTDGHsDsGcBcAJYFM7wFzwNpwE4EtIBzAGlwJLKNNnyssIF0BeLAIgEZXj5WAmLngGYBrACwiArKwYBYAFDyIMBMlQtMHEf26thO8TqkN4AQ2jwlcANzzFUVNCSQAJgFkU0E4SQsAFJABXAFt2dHh6YnlAoN4wiKjgwTiacki5aNFk2hIEoIks1PkASngmAD54AG9bOQBfGwU5Rxd3aE9vXwA6btVYEpB4JBwccBwMAEFwgAccJBNnUxxCYKcEIIDUJDxYAAsh+B2TADckU0QAqYAbU9gATynT0fgAI1Ops0cF2HAz2dR3nAmIJIZA4TqwaC+XgSCQANiK8mabg8XiQXW6Gk4Om0QhEBh4RiKDXkQA)