# Why does this Typescript function return this warning?

Tags: typescript

Given this recursive Typescript function:

```
const checkNested = ((obj: any, attr: string, ...rest: any[]): boolean => {
  if (obj === undefined || obj === null) return false
  if (rest.length === 0 && obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) return true
  return checkNested(obj[attr], ...rest)
})
```

My editor highlights the `...rest` on the return statement with this error:

```
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
```

What does it mean, and how can I change it to satisfy the warning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768781/a-spread-argument-must-either-have-a-tuple-type-or-be-passed-to-a-rest-parameter

Comment: Your "spread argument" `rest` encompasses `attr: string`. Since the first element of `rest` may not be a string, it's unsafe. Yes, you are using `any[]` as the type of `rest`, but this isn't the standard type check that emits the error - it's the check for varargs.

Comment: Notice that when I cast it to a **tuple** (with the first element being a string so it matches the call signature), the error goes away: https://tsplay.dev/WKryym

Comment: And this code is obviously wrong at runtime, but demonstrates that passing a spread argument to a rest parameter is valid: https://tsplay.dev/WJry5W

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768781/a-spread-argument-must-either-have-a-tuple-type-or-be-passed-to-a-rest-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code once :

```
const checkNested = (obj: any, ...rest: string[]): boolean => {
  if (obj === undefined || obj === null) return false;
  if (!rest.length) return true;
  
  return rest.every(attr => {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object' || !obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) return false;
    obj = obj[attr];
    return true;
  });
};
```